# std::find not operating as expected

Tags: c++, find

std::find is not evaluating as I expected.

I have a vector lexeme_ defined as

```
static const std::string delimiters_[] = {" ", ",", "(", ")", ";", "=", ".", "*", "-"};

static std::vector<std::string> lexeme_(std::begin(delimiters_), std::end(delimiters_));
```

I have an evaluation using `std::find` defined as

```
while ( std::find(lexeme_.begin(),lexeme_.end(),std::string(&commandLine_.at(position_))) == lexeme_.end())             
{
    // Concat each successive alphanumeric character to 'token'
    token += commandLine_.at(position_);
    // Update the index into 'commandLine'
    position_ += 1;
}
```

The evaluation is supposed to compare a `char` in lexeme_ to a `char` in commandLine similar to this Java expression

```
!lexeme.contains(Character.toString(commandLine.charAt(position)))
```

The evaluation is supposed to compare `char`s and if it determines a `char` in `delimiters` is satisfied in the comparison, then the while loop will exit.

Testcase

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>    

static const std::string delimiters_[] = {" ", ",", "(", ")", ";", "=", ".", "*", "-"};

static std::vector<std::string> lexeme_(std::begin(delimiters_), std::end(delimiters_));

std::string commandLine = "check me";

while (std::find(lexeme_.begin(),lexeme_.end(),std::string(&commandLine_.at(position_))) == lexeme_.end())             
{
    std::cout "I should stop printing when encountering a space ' ' << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you construct a complete test-case to demonstrate this?

Comment: @DrewDormann needs citation. As stated, that is ludicrous. It is certainly not "certainly" faster.

Comment: So what is the problem? What does this code do, and what did you expect it to do, and how does what it does do differ from what you expect it to do? In short, http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: It looks like you're trying to construct an (expression) parser. Would you like help with that? See e.g. [Expression Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464969/boostspirit-expression-parser/8468822#8468822), [Veryfiying Algebraic Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123412/how-to-verify-algebraic-statements-using-boostspirit/15123959#15123959), [Calculator Sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486531/boostspiritqi-defining-a-calculator-for-nullaries/15488691#15488691) (note, I like [tag:boost-spirit] and [tag:coco-cpp])

Comment: @DrewDormann You're gonna have to show some evidence for that claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor for your temporary comparison string is incorrect. It isn't building a single-character string, it's building a string starting at that character and going to the end of the original string, if you're lucky - there might be some `std::string` implementation out there somewhere that doesn't automatically zero terminate the internal buffer.

So instead of this:

```
std::string(&commandLine_.at(position_))
```

Use:

```
std::string(1, commandLine_.at(position_))
```

Comment: Thank you.  Also, converting `delimiters_` to a `char` array and making `lexeme_` a `std::vector<char>` works as well.

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
 std::string(&commandLine_.at(position_))
```

Creates an `std::string` object by passing a pointer to a `char` object. However, a pointer to a `char` object is a (null-terminated) C-string, not a pointer to a single character.

There is no constructor of `std::string` that accepts a single character. You could make your vector a vector of `char`s, and then search for `commandLine_.at(position_)` inside that vector.

However, judging from your test case, it seems to me all you want is the [`find_first_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) member function of `std::string`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string commandLine = "Check me";
    std::string delimiters = " ,();=.*-";
    auto pos = commandLine.find_first_of(delimiters);
    std::cout << pos;
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%243877).

Comment: BTW he goes in to the while loop if he didn't find; not when he found. (whatever he is looking for)

Comment: @stardust_: Right, that was the result of a copy-paste gone wrong. I edited anyway, thank you